# “The process cannot access the file” error in Winforms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I made an .sdf file (SQL CE) from an XML file. When the file is ready, I want to attach it to an e-mail. But when I try to attach it, I get this error:

```
The process cannot access the file......because it is being used by another process
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an SqlCeConnection open on the file? Is it open in Visual Studio?

I suggest you use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) so you can identify the process which has a handle on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that because SQLCE databases are run in-proc with your program that you can't get exclusive access to the file while your program is running.

Comment: Either that or the db engine has a lock on it.